# MySQL subquery limit 1

Tags: mysql, sql

I have an sql query that returns a list of residential units, and a subquery that is supposed to get the last entered bill for that unit.

However when I add LIMIT 1 to the subquery, no bill entries are returned? If I leave it out, I get duplicate unit rows depending on the number of bill for the unit.

```
select * from unit u
left join (select id as billId, unit_id, added_on, end_reading, bill_type from bills
order by id desc) b ON unit_id = u.id
where community_Id = 1
and unit_section = 7
and unit_floor in (1,2,3,4,5)
order by unit_floor, display_order asc;
```

Anyone know how I can the subquery result limited to 1 bill?

Comment: you could try to add a `group by u.id` at the end, without adding the limit 1 and check if that works for you

Comment: have you tried a select unique on the sub query, what effect does that have?

Comment: It looks to me like you're selecting all bills, not just the bills for the one residential unit you're interested in, thus the limit is always returning the same (i.e., the very last) bill entry, not the latest for the one residential unit you are querying at that time.

Comment: After display_order? Does not run at all.

Comment: At least I can tell you why this fails. You limit your subquery (derived table) to one row (the one with max id). Then you ask to join with u using the unit_id which doesn't match.

Comment: SELECT UNIQUE? You mean DISINCT? Does not do anything.

Comment: Thorsten, well, the query is working, it is just returning too many hits.

Comment: No, I mean when you add LIMIT to the subquery. Sorry for having been unclear.

Comment: @RobertBenedetto `group by` goes before `order by`

Comment: @CatalinDeaconescu that did it! Post it as an answer and ill mark it

Comment: @RobertBenedetto thanks and glad that I could help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using joins that duplicate your results, add a `group by` statement. It's an alternative of the `distinct` from a simple select

```
select * from unit u
left join (select id as billId, unit_id, added_on, end_reading, bill_type from bills
order by id desc) b ON unit_id = u.id
where community_Id = 1
and unit_section = 7
and unit_floor in (1,2,3,4,5)
group by u.id
order by unit_floor, display_order asc;
```

Comment: This will not specify which rows values from the bills table (from the sub query) will be returned. The row MySQL chooses is undefined.

Comment: All rows from the sub query will be returned and used, and the `group by` will aggregate the resulting combination by the variable provided (`u.id`). If there are duplicates those will be merged into a single row.

Comment: A single row for each group by column value will be returned, but the other columns can come from any row (NOT merged). For example with your query if for a unit there are 2 rows with a matching unit_id on the bills table then all but one will be eliminated by the GROUP BY. Which rows fields are eliminated is not defined. It may be the ones that equate to the max id from the bills table (ie the required ones), but could also be from any other row with a matching unit_id (or even from different rows for each column). http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-extensions.html

Comment: @Kickstart I admit that in some (most) cases this might not be correct solution, but for that we would need to know exactly what relation is between unit and bills, what each represents and the limitations for each. I was just answering to the request of the OP to limit the number of rows.

Answer (score 0):

Think you will need a sub query to get the first (lowest) id for each unit_id from the bills table. Then use that to join between the unit and bills table, getting the other matching columns from bills for that lowest id

```
SELECT u.*, bills.*
FROM unit u
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
(
    SELECT unit_id, MIN(id) AS min_id
    FROM bills
    GROUP BY unit_id
) b ON b.unit_id = u.id
LEFT OUTER JOIN bills
ON b.unit_id = bills.unit_id
AND b.min_id = bills.id
WHERE u.community_Id = 1
AND u.unit_section = 7
AND u.unit_floor in (1,2,3,4,5)
ORDER BY u.unit_floor, u.display_order asc;
```

Comment: Thanks for the effort, but @Catalin already gave a positive answer :)